# Node.js controlling no of post calls per second

Tags: node.js, post

I am subscribing to an inhouse api (POST request) that restricts me to make 5 calls per second.

node.js is being used to make these rest api calls.

How to write code to restrict the no. of api calls invoked per second ?

Comment: Is your node app a utility (i.e.: is it initiating the calls) or is it acting more as a proxy (i.e.: end user(s) making requests)

Comment: Node.js is invoking the calls

Comment: Then @Stijn Martens answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setInterval(makeAPICall, 200);` to execute the API calls every 200 milliseconds.

Every execution of the `makeAPICall` function you make one call from a queue.

```
var queue = [
    {
        arg1 : 'arg1value',
        arg2 : 'arg2value'
    },
    {
        arg1 : 'arg1value',
        arg2 : 'arg2value'
    }
];

setInterval(function() {
    var arguments = queue[0];

    // API call function, using arguments
    makeAPICall(arguments.arg1, arguments.arg2);

    // Remove from queue
    queue.splice(0, 1);
}, 200);
```

Comment: I am using setInterval(makeAPICall,200,argumentsToApIcall). My argumants are in an array and for every record in the array the api call must be made. How do i do setInterval in loop and also clear it ?

Comment: Ok now I get what u r saying. So once the queue becomes empty i should clear the interval